# Get header of response with ky?

Tags: post, vuex, nuxt.js

i wanna create auth on website with vuex, but when i post email and password, response header **return null**

```
const actions = {
  // Get Token
  async login(context, payload) {
    let data = null
    try {
      data = await http.post(
        process.env.apiUrl + '/api/content/create?type=User',
        {
          body: payload
        }
      )
    } catch (err) {}
    console.log(data.headers.get('Authorization'))
    // context.dispatch('get_user', data.headers.Get('Authorization'))
  },
}
```

But in the browser network tab:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhY2Nlc3MiOiJjb2xkQGNvbGQuY29sZCIsImF1ZCI6bnVsbCwiZXhwIjoxNTg0NTQxMzkzLCJpYXQiOm51bGwsImlzcyI6bnVsbCwianRpIjpudWxsLCJuYmYiOm51bGwsInN1YiI6bnVsbH0.fIErBy9QklFk4lv73p76ExIpuupuKYkRnDgV0t2L1wk
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public
Etag: MTU4MzkzNjUzMw==
Date: Wed, 11 Mar 2020 14:23:14 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: you need to access the parameter data inside the try block, not inside the catch block

Comment: here it is **catch (err) {}**

Answer (score 1):

You should access the parameter "data" inside the try block. catch block will be executed only when error throw with in try block

```
const actions = {
 // Get Token
 async login(context, payload) {
let data = null
try {
  data = await http.post(
    process.env.apiUrl + '/api/content/create?type=User',
    {
      body: payload
    }
  )
  context.dispatch('get_user', data.headers.Get('Authorization'))
} catch (err) {}
 console.log(err)

 },
}
```

Comment: this not work cause `catch (err) {}` are closed already and `console.log(err)` getting error (err undefined), and `data.headers.Get('Authorization')` **ky** doesnt have **Get** method cause in `fetch` this method called get, but anyway **return null** @Vigikaran